# Dynamics CRM Authentication Without Active Directory

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

We have employees that work in our company but not in the central office. We installed Dynamics CRM 2016 in the central office. Some users do not exist in the central office active directory. How can we define these users to authenticate and work with CRM?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to add a user that not exists in AD or trusted AD. I assume that these users who doesn't exist in central office AD exists in another AD. If yes then it is matter of configuring proper trusts between domains.